# Hibernate Ehcache in GAE throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.rmi.server.UID is a restricted class

Tags: java, hibernate, google-app-engine, rmi, ehcache

I'm new to Google App Engine. Earlier I had created one dynamic web application using jsf, hibernate, java and glassfish server. now I converted that application structure to Google App engine structure. so now I'm using GAE and local MySQL database.

I created Simple Dynamic web application with Runtime Target GAE Server. I'm able to call Jsf login page but unable to login on application cause of getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.rmi.server.UID is a restricted class`.

*Full Stack Trace here*:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.rmi.server.UID is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:52)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.<init>(Cache.java:191)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:291)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createDefaultCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:241)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.configure(CacheManager.java:262)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:196)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:183)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:343)
    at org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider.start(EhCacheProvider.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1176)
    at hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory.<clinit>(HibernateSessionFactory.java:31)
    at hibernate.UsersDAO.login(UsersDAO.java:98)
    at utils.LoginBean.loginProject(LoginBean.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 43 more
```

*My HibernateSessionFactory class (Piece of code where i'm getting error):*

```
private static String CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION = "hibernate.cfg.xml";
    private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Session>();
    private  static Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    private static org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static String configFile = CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION;

    static {
            try {
            configuration.configure(configFile);
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(); // <==here getting error
                } catch (Exception e) {                        
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
```

I unable to understand where i'm doing mistake. If anyone having same experience then please share me.
I search this exception on google and get many answer but that answer doesn't suit because here getting exception in different library.
Thanks in advance and appreciated.

Comment: Stack trace is incomplete. Root causes are missing. Answer is over there. Perhaps your copypasted only a part or didn't look in server log? This is at least not a JSF/Hibernate specific problem. JSF is just the user interface here and Hibernate is just the ORM here.

Comment: Ok @BalusC , Then what i need to check? I have been stuck please suggest me what should i do? because I pasted in all the src file and web pages and did server configuration also. My login page is calling but i'm unable to login.

Comment: Stack trace is incomplete. Root causes are missing. Answer is over there. Perhaps your copypasted only a part or didn't look in server log?

Comment: After trace server log i got where i'm getting error ( sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(); ) so update question.

Comment: Great, we get somewhere. I improved the question further. Now it's a matter of waiting for answers.

Comment: What did it say in the Google App Engine developer's guide about this error when you looked it up?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using quite old version of EhCache.
This doc http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/integrations/googleappengine.html say you should use 2.3+ version to avoid `java.rmi.server.UID is a restricted class` exception.